# Is PHP strtotime function when given format of only m/d/Y guaranteed to return first second of that day?

Tags: php, mysql, strtotime

`strtotime()` returns number of seconds since so and so date. OK. So it's all in seconds. Now, if you give a date format which consists of only day, month and year, what time does it return in terms of seconds. The very first second of the day, the last second or undefined in between? The manual does not provide any guidance and common sense would assume the first second. Why is this significant? It could be when comparing or computing time interval between a fully defined date and a partially defined datetime (one without hours, minutes and seconds).

```
    strtotime("1/1/2014")
```

Is this "guaranteed," as opposed to expected, to return the very first second of the new year?

Comment: Why not explicitly enforce it? `strtotime("1/1/2014 00:00:00")`

Comment: @Pekka, Never thought of that. In the absence of any express assurance in the manual, your solution is certainly  'guaranteed" to return the first second. Case closed! Thanks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will always return first second of that day:

```php
echo date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime("1/1/2014"));
# 2014-01-01 00:00:00
```

<kbd>[**demo**](http://3v4l.org/G017e)</kbd>

but to be sure, just enforce time like @Pekka suggested:

```php
echo strtotime("1/1/2014 00:00:00");
```

Comment: @Pekka웃: will not put my hand in fire for this one ;) So I have edited and put your comment in the answer.

Comment: The short answer is **Yes**. While not mentioned in the documentation, [the code speaks for itself](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/date/php_date.c#1434): of interest is [`timelib_fill_holes()`](http://lxr.php.net/xref/PHP_5_6/ext/date/lib/parse_date.re#2189), which is called internally by `strtotime()`.

Comment: @salathe: nice research, but we should check if this code is also in older versions; like 4.x

Comment: @salathe, Thanks for the research but you will agree that the proposed solution is code-independent until expected behavior is committed to in the documentation.

Comment: Glavić feel free! @Samir the proposed *alternative* is fine, though it's not an answer to the question posed. Feel free to make/suggest documentation changes yourself by either editing the documentation at https://edit.php.net (we use the DocBook format), or filing a bug report at https://bugs.php.net.

Comment: @salathe: I did. `fill_holes()` function came in 5.1.0 version, bellow that it doesn't exists. Probably is implemented in some other function...

Answer (score 2):

It will return the time from 00:00:00, e.g. `strtotime("1/1/2014");` = `strtotime("1/1/2014 00:00:00");`

In case you need to be sure, just use:

```
strtotime("1/1/2014 00:00:00");
```